# Applications that require Java are having strange tab namings

Tags: java, eclipse, dbeaver

I am having a problem with applications that require Java to run, like Eclipse, DBeaver and so on. I have Java 11 JDK installed, but the tabs on each of these applications are showing weird names. I do think that the problem is because of Java and I really wanted to know if anybody else had this kind of problem, and how they dealt with it. It is driving me crazy. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling JDK but nothing successfully resolved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced the issue that you are seeing however I can suggest a possible reason for this.
Java 9+ represents Strings using UTF-8, rather than UTF-16 (I think), which was used previously. This means that characters will take a different number of bytes in their representation. I would suggest re-installing the packages which are showing the issue, these (if they are java based) have presumably been built with a newer java and the new install will hopefully not display this issue.

Comment: Java 9+ does not use UTF-8 for strings. The internal representation of strings is either an ISO-8859-1 byte array if all the characters in the string can be represented that way, otherwise the byte array is UTF-16. The String APIs are still UTF-16 as always. This can all be disabled with a command line flag. Eclipse doesn't have any problem with any of this.

Comment: @greg-449 are you sure, I understood this was one of the changes which had occurred on the move to java 9?

Comment: The use of ISO-8859-1 was the change in Java 9 - so called 'compact strings'. But this is all hidden away and does not change the String APIs in any way. It is very easy to see looking at the source of the String class. String now has a field called `coder` with a value of `LATIN1` or `UTF16` (Latin 1 is another name for ISO-8859-1)

Comment: Thanks, I see that now, this is useful knowledge. Do you think this would impact on the OP's issue?

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse run fine on Java 8 through Java 13, older versions fails to run at all. I can't find any report of something like this is in the Eclipse bugs database so I really don't have any idea what is happening.

Comment: well, actually these apps have already a a choosing option about the encoding technique. Anyways I tried uninstalling and installing again those, but still the same problem occurs.